# how to replace a node with all of its children in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

I was wondering how to replace a node of a non-binary tree with its children.  For example, I'd start with a structure like so:

```
        a
     / / \ \
    b  c  d e
   /\  /    /\\
  f  g h    i jk
```

and end up with this if I target node `e` to be replaced with its children

```
          a
     / / \ \ \ \
    b  c  d i j k
   /\  / 
  f  g h
```

in JSON, the initial structure would look like this:

```
{
  "id": "a",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "b",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "f",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "g",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "c",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "h",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "d",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "e",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "i",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "j",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "k",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You iterate through the children of `e`, adding them to `a` as children.  Then you remove `e` as a child of `a`.  I'm confused as to where you're stuck.

Comment: Which language are you using to process the tree? Could you add your attempt and show where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will become much easier if you changed the JSON sturcture a bit. 
For every node store the parent of each node and its immediate children.

#### New JSON Structure

```js
[
  {"id": "a", "parent": null, "children" : ["b", "c", "d", "e"] },
  {"id": "b", "parent": "a",  "children" : ["f", "g"]},
  {"id": "c", "parent": "a",  "children" : ["h"]},
  {"id": "d", "parent": "a",  "children" : []},
  {"id": "e", "parent": "a",  "children" : ["i", "j", "k"]}
]
```

#### Algorithm

Lets say your target node is `e`.

Now all you need to do is change the parents of the immediate children of `e` to `a` since `a` is the parent of `e`. And then delete `e`.

This will preserve the subtree structure of the children of `e`. If you do not want that then you must recursively assign `a` as the parent to all children of `e` not just the immediate ones.

Comment: is there a way to functionally achieve this if we pass the proposed json structure and some condition that needs to be fulfilled such as checking to see if the id of the node is `e`?

Comment: @reactor I did not understand what you just said. Could you perhaps ask again in layman terms ?